# How to select max not-unique item in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is the problem. I have for example such a table in MySQL

```
 Model | Make | Year
Jaguar |  XF  | 2016
Jaguar |  XF  | 2017
Jaguar |  BM  | 2013
Jaguar |  BM  | 2014
```

I need to select unique Line based on the max Year and combination of Model + Make. At the end the result should be:

```
Jaguar | XF | 2017
Jaguar |  BM  | 2014
```

so that i have only newest car of the model. Thank You!

Comment: What did you tried and what challenge are you facing? You shouldn't expect much contributions unless you them with the community otherwise, your post may just appear to portray you are simply looking for a ready cooked and free solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you group your data then aggregate functions like `max()` apply to each group  and not the complete resultset

```
select model, make, max(year)
from your_table
group by model, make
```